# How do report types correlate to database world?

Tags: force.com, reporting

In Salesforce, we are given 4 report types, and I'm trying to see how they correlate to the database world. I think these are right, but I'm not sure on the joined and matrix reports

- Tabular  --> allows you to do select from where queries
- Summary --> allows you to do the above with group bys and aggregate functions. Though the      aggregate functions are not required. They're similiar but not equal to group bys
- Matrix -->? close to pivot tables maybe?
- Joins --> ? inner joins I think?

Comment: Are you asking how the reports correlate to SOQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

- Tabular - excel like view of data. The raw selected data
- Summary - Correct / also min required to start graphing data
- Matrix - close enough, this is what I say
- Joined - Like aggregating data from multiple sheets in excel / correlate different data sets which share a common key like AccountId